# How do you find all the objects/instances in a folder/model with a specific attribute in lua/roblox lua

Tags: lua, instance, roblox

I am working on a game in Roblox and need a little help finding objects with attribute values. It is a tycoon for anyone here familiar with Roblox. I would like to know how you can find all instances with say the attribute `Unlock_ID: 1`, and then when you press the corresponding button, it will unlock it, or make it show up on the screen. I know how to make the objects unlock, I just don't know how to get all the objects with that attribute.

To put it more simply:

I want to find all the objects/instances inside a section with a specific attribute and a specific value and put them inside a table.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71897970/2860267

Comment: @Kylaaa Sort of, I saw that before but I don't know how to add it to a table.

Comment: @Hack.cpp `table.insert`. Also, if the indices don't matter and if the table will be used for checking existence then you can also use the keys of the table to store these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for i,v in ipairs` loops along with the `Folder:GetChildren()` as your iteration directory. Then you can insert the instance (using `table.insert(table,element)` into a table if their `part:GetAttribute('Unlock_ID')` is equal to 1. To achieve this, simply do the following:

```lua
local partsWithAttribute = {}
local folder = workspace.Folder -- change this to whatever path you want to iterate through

for i,part in ipairs(folder:GetChildren()) do
    if part:GetAttribute('Unlock_ID') == 1 then
        table.insert(partsWithAttribute,part)
    end
end
```